# how to perform an action right after user finish inputting data in the textfield?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UITextField` that will be used to input the data of time (10,15,30 minutes etc). I want right after the user manually input the minute data, then I will check, if it is more than zero or not ( negative or zero is not allowed), if the value is below 1 then I will show the alert.

I have tried to use the code below, but it doesn't work :

```
func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField == numberReminderTextField {
        let valueNumber = Int(numberReminderTextField.text ?? "0") ?? 0
        if valueNumber < 1 {
            showAlert(alertTitle: "Sorry", alertMessage: "The number you input is invalid, please input the number that more than zero.", actionTitle: "Back")
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: the alert doesn't show up

Comment: yes, because in the VC I have more than one TextField so I think I need to specify it

Comment: Have you connected UITextField's delegate to the VC ? And somehow called resignFirstResponder ?

Comment: Including your 'showAlert' code is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you shouldn't do this checking in `textFieldShouldEndEditing`. 
You can do the checking in `textFieldDidEndEditing` or set your custom observer on `.editingChanged` control event.

I.E.

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yourCheckAction), for: .editingChanged)
```

If the alert still not show up, you should look into your `showAlert` function.